# Parameter not being passed to controller method in laravel when using route method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code in my anchor tag in my laravel application:

```
<a href="{{ route('showQualityResult' , compact(Session::get('quality-data'))) }}">Submited Quality Check</a>
```

My route is set to run the following method when clicked on the above link:

```
public function showQualityResult($qualityData) {
        return $qualityData;
        // return view('quality-result' , compact($qualityData));
    }
```

Now when i click on the link, i get the following error:

[image]

Why am i getting a `Missing argument 1` error when i clearly am passing data as a parameter in the  tag like so below:

```
<a href="{{ route('showQualityResult' , compact(Session::get('quality-data'))) }}">Submited Quality Check</a>
```

Why is the parameter not being passed to the method ?

Comment: you need to send the parameter in route..

Answer (score 3):

Your route from your previous question:

```
Route::get('/showQualityResult', 'QualityCheckController@showQualityResult');
```

To pass the parameter, you should define it. So, it'll look like this:

```
Route::get('showQualityResult/{data}', 'QualityCheckController@showQualityResult');
```

And `showQualityResult()` method should accept it:

```
public function showQualityResult($data)
{
    ....
```

I'd recommend you to read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-parameters) to understand how it works.

Comment: i have the following route setup now `Route::get('showQualityResult/{data}', [
    'as' => 'showQualityResult', 
    'uses' => 'QualityCheckController@showQualityResult'
]);`

and now i get the following error: http://imgur.com/gi02rgc .

Comment: Route::get('/showQualityResult/{id}', 'QualityCheckController@showQualityResult')->where('id','[0-9]+');