# Error even before controller method has been invoked in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code in my view:

```
@if(Session::has('quality-data'))
        <a href="{{ route('showQualityResult' , compact(Session::get('quality-data'))) }}">Submited Quality Check</a>
    @endif
```

Now when I open this view in the frontend I get the following error:

[image]

The method that's invoked when clicked on the a tag is the following:

```
public function showQualityResult($qualityData) {
        return $qualityData;
        // return view('quality-result' , compact($qualityData));
    }
```

Now even though I have not clicked on the a tag I am still getting an error that the parameter for the function hasn't been passed. Why is this?

Just the fact that I have the below lines of code in my view:

```
 @if(Session::has('quality-data'))
            <a href="{{ route('showQualityResult' , compact(Session::get('quality-data'))) }}">Submited Quality Check</a>
        @endif
```

Makes my application not work.

Comment: same issue as your duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190379/parameter-not-being-passed-to-controller-method-in-laravel-when-using-route-meth

Answer (score 2):

I think your error is due to the usage of compact .. that does not match with the expected data required.

Indeed, your route require the `data` argument. Compact will create an array where the key the string in parameter, and the value associated. 
Is `Session::get('quality-data')` return 'data' ? And `$data` exists ?

So, you should write:

```
@if(Session::has('quality-data'))
  <a href="{{ route('showQualityResult' , ['data' => Session::get('quality-data')]) }}">Submited Quality Check</a>
@endif
```

> If this works ... so, you will be able to simplify the writing.